# ArcMap WMS cannot see

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wms, web-service

I want to open a WMS connection in ArcMap. When I call the related service, ArcMap can access all layers. When I want to view any layer from the layer list, ArcMap tries to establish a connection for a long time, but cannot access the data. The WMS address is as follows: https://cbs.kayseri.bel.tr/proxy.ashx?MAKSADRES&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities

I am not getting any errors. How can I go about the subject?

Comment: removed qgis tag - question is arcgis related.

Comment: I wish someone could help with the problems.

Comment: also wms service is running in qgis.

Comment: wms with proxy returns "<ows:ExceptionText>Request parameter is missing!</ows:ExceptionText>
"

Comment: What path should I follow? I can successfully use the service by marking "ignore getmap-getcapa.." in Qgis. i can open the same url address in arcmap. the entire layer list comes in successfully. there is no error. and I do not encounter any errors while loading the data. but I can't access it as an image. I can temporarily serve this problem as wms with qgis server and open it in arcmap, but qgis server is running very slow. There is no slowness when using it in qgis.

Comment: Request https://cbs.kayseri.bel.tr/proxy.ashx?MAKSADRES&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities works just fine.

Comment: yes yes i know but i cant see in arcmap. I've been dealing with this for a very long time. I don't know where the problem originates from. I really need someone's help. arcmap can call layers. but the image is not coming. as if I was studying a different region in the coordinate system. The weird thing is, I don't get any errors.

Comment: The problem is misconfiguration of the server. The URLs in the GetCapabilities should be the proxy URL,.  In addition to that the XML response is invalid.  The `MinScaleDenominator` and the `MaxScaleDenominator` elements should appear after the `Style` content

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the capabilities document, it appears that the GetMap URL is not on https://**cbs.kayberi.bel.tr**, but on https://**kpsv2.nvi.gov.tr**/Services/WMSService/Get.

This URL does not seem to return anything (at least, the network connection is closed immediately). Ignoring getmap-getcapabilities solves this, because QGIS will assume the base URL will be the same as the one you specified.

If you are in control of the proxy running on https://cbs.kayseri.bel.tr/proxy.ashx you might be able to dynamically alter the URLs in the response to the GetCapabilities request.

Another option would be to save the capabilities document, manually modify the URLs, and host it on a server of your own. In this case replace all occurrences of `https://kpsv2.nvi.gov.tr/Services/WMSService/Get` with `https://cbs.kayseri.bel.tr/proxy.ashx?MAKSADRES`

Comment: yes, what you said is very true. I have not gone further than this stage. When I view this service in ArcMap, I can access the layer names from the server. I can't get an image to the screen where I'm displaying the respective layers. No error. How can I go about using it in Arcmap? Is there any possibility to define "Ignore" property to ArcMap? Additionally, I heard that WMS addresses do not support https. Could the problem be related to this?

Comment: "proxy.ashx?" in the URI Can I find the WMS address as an example to fill in the field? So what I want to say is if I learned the proxy service, what should be my writing rules in WMS?

Comment: No, there is no option in ArcMap to ignore the capabilities document. The only way would be somehow modify the capabilities document in one of the two ways I described. And the transport used (i.e. http or http) is of no consequence. In fact, the protocol (WMS) doesn'has no concept of 'knowing' what the type of transport is.

Comment: i did publish with qgis server wms; after i can open the wms successed but qgis server very slow running. i can show the layers in 0.5 second in qgis but arcmap 7-8 seconds. what is the reason of this?

Comment: I don't know, you could [ask](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a separate question about that

Comment: Not all `https://kpsv2.nvi.gov.tr/Services/WMSService/Get` the GetCapabilities OnlineResource would be the URL to the static capabilities file